# implement validates_uniqueness_of :attr as base error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation

I want to validate an attribute with scope of other, but since they both have equal part in this validation I do not want the error to be assigned to any one of attributes (but to base errors).

I would like to avoid custom validation, I looking for something like:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :attr, scope: [:attr1, :attr2], as: :base
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to add errors to `:base` without subclassing or monkeypatching the default validator(s), which would be a lot more work then writing some custom validation:

```
validate :attr1_does_not_equal_attr2

def attr1_does_not_equal_attr2
  errors.add(:base, 'attr1 should not equal attr2') if attr1 == attr2
end
```

#### Different solution

Assuming your `validates_uniqueness_of` code was working perfect except for the error message not attached to `:base`.

Write a `after_validation` that sets a base error when an error is detected in one of the attributes, something like (untested):

```
def after_validation
  if errors[:attr] || errors[:attr1] || errors[:attr2]
    errors.add(:base, 'Duplicate values detected')
  end
end
```

Comment: It is a bit more complicated than that. I need to verify uniqueness of attribute in the whole DB. The parallel solution should be     errors.add(:base, message) unless Model.where(attr1: attr1, attr2: attr2).where(['id != ?', id]).exists?

Comment: @sudo I added a new solution that should work if your validation already was perfect except for the `:base` part.